# How do you match a specific word from multiple lines using regex?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I'm trying to match the word "first_name" from the below snippet:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
  </div>
```

Using something like this regular expression:

```
<div class="field">((\n|.)*?)<\/div>
```

gives me:

```
<%= f.label :first_name %><br />
<%= f.text_field :first_name %>
```

(Here is the expression in action: http://rubular.com/r/uh6SZ6EGcQ)

Since I only want "first_name", what regular expression should I use such that I can match only the "first_name"?

Comment: Why are you trying to process ERB with ruby? :)

Comment: Sorry about that. I made the question more specific. I don't know if regex in ruby is different from other languages since I'm a complete noob when it comes to regex.

Comment: No, I'm just wondering why you're handling ERB in the first place...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use the regex

```
:\w+
```

To match symbols.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how I would use that? Is it something like <div class="field">((\n|.)*?)(:\w+)<\/div>?

Comment: No, just `:\w+`. From the small amount of information you've given this is all you need...

Comment: That was easy :) Sorry about my regex language barriers by the way. Doing this <div class="field">(\n|.)*?(\w+)(\n|.)*?<\/div> worked perfectly. Thanks so much JT!